# Dynamic placeholder for Left and Right column in Sitecore JSS NextJs Rendering Component

Tags: sxa, jss, sxa-jss

I have `SXA-JSS Next.JS` based component for `Sitecore 10.3.0`, I want to have 2 placeholders with the different key, but with a dynamic suffix. e.g. I need 2 equal columns.

In CMS, I Created two placeholder using these key `twocolumn-left-{*}` and `twocolumn-right-{*}` and on jsx component update placeholder as below :

```
const twoColumnLeftPhKey = "twocolumn-left-${props.params.DynamicPlaceholderId}";
const twoColumnRightPhKey = "twocolumn-right-${props.params.DynamicPlaceholderId}";
<div>
  <Placeholder name='{twoColumnLeftPhKey}' rendering={rendering}/>
</div>
<div>
  <Placeholder name='{twoColumnRightPhKey}' rendering={rendering}/>
</div>
```

I am getting error in browser console for this :

```
Placeholder twocolumn-right-2 is not found in the current rendering data.
```

And on Experience Editor :

```
A rendering error occured: Cannot read properties of undefined (rendering attributes)
```

Is it expected behavior? How to overcome it and get different suffixes?

Comment: What if you just try to use `twocolumn-left` and `twocolumn-right` placeholders and let Sitecore handle all the dynamic keys thing?

Comment: Does your rendering parameters template for that component inherit from the dynamic placeholders template?

Comment: @SerhiiShushliapin - I have already tried it, but it is not behaving as a dynamic placeholder, and using the same key for all components added on that placeholder.

Comment: @RichardSeal - yes rendering parameter template already inherit from dynamic placeholder templates, I created this rendering by cloning promo component, so all required settings are in place.